# Want this random number generator to generate 10 answers and add to a list box

Tags: vb.net, loops, listbox

I am trying to keep some skills by writing a application during my semester break at school and have found some issues I don't know the answer to.

I am trying to get this code to generate 10 results and concatenate them to a `ListBox` named `lstPhoneNumbers`.  Here is what I've tried:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'Calculate Random Prefix based upon selected city
    If lstBoxCity.SelectedItem.ToString = "Bethany" Then

        ' Initialize the random-number generator.
        Randomize()

        Dim Bethany As String() = {"298", "342", "443", "644", "712", "755", "759", "777", "779", "847"}

        ' Generate random value between 1 and then length of your Bethany array
        Dim randomBethany As String = Bethany(CInt((Bethany.Count * Rnd()) + 1))

        MsgBox(randomBethany.ToString)
    End If
```

*** Edited for Steven Doggart****

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'Calculate Random Prefix based upon selected city
    If lstBoxCity.SelectedItem.ToString = "Bethany" Then
        Dim Bethany As String() = {"298", "342", "443", "644", "712", "755", "759", "777", "779", "847"}
        For i As Integer = 0 To 9
            lstPhoneNumbers.Items.Add(Bethany(RandomPrefix.Next(0, Bethany.Count - 1)))
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should be using the `Random` class rather than the old-VB6-style `Rnd` method.  Even if you are using `Rnd`, you should, ideally, only be calling `Randomize` once, when the program starts, not every time the button is clicked.  To do this with the `Random` class, first you should create a `Random` object as a private field on your form, like this:

```
Public Class MyForm
    Private rand As New Random()
    ' ...
```

Then, in your button click event handler, you need to create a `For` loop which generates 10 random numbers, adding each one to the `ListBox` control as it does so:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    '...
    For i As Integer = 0 to 9
         lstPhoneNumbers.Items.Add(Bethany(rand.Next(0, Bethany.Count - 1)))
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: When I try to use ".Next" It isn't recognizing it, and I have changed my code to use Random instead of rnd.

Comment: For i As Integer = 0 To 9
                lstPhoneNumbers.Items.Add(Bethany(RandomPrefix.Next(0, Bethany.Count - 1)))
            Next

Comment: Says Next is is not a member of 'System.Array'.

Comment: Can you show the full method?  It won't format properly if you add it as a comment, so please just edit your question and add it in there.

Comment: Edited for your approval.

Comment: Its funny the .Next turns blue on here but in Visual Studio it just stays black like normal Text

Comment: Yeah, I don't know either.  The code that you posted is correct and works fine in my Visual Studio.  It's probably something syntactically wrong with code elsewhere in that file.